# Create lightning component dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I know there are so many questions available in forum regarding Dynamically create Lightning component using **$A.createComponent(....);**

I have little bit different requirement. while creating the component i am passing the the type dynamically. Means it can be any type of the component. 'Date, String, Text, Textarea, Boolean etc..'

So I have written the code below

```
var componentTag = '';
var uiComponent = [];
if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "DOUBLE") {
    componentTag = "lightning:input";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "DATE") {
    componentTag = "ui:inputDate";
    uiComponent.push('"aura:id": "text-Value","label": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + '","value": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + '","displayDatePicker": true');
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "TEXTAREA") {
    componentTag = "lightning:textarea";
    uiComponent.push('\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + '",\"value\": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + '",\"maxlength\": 180,\"class\": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldName + '"');
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "STRING") {
    componentTag = "lightning:input";
    uiComponent.push('"aura:id": "text-Value","label": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + '","class": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldName + '"');
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "PERCENT") {
    componentTag = "lightning:input";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"findableAuraId\",\"type\": \"number\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "CURRENCY") {
    componentTag = "ui:inputCurrency";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "DATETIME") {
    componentTag = "ui:inputDateTime";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"displayDatePicker\": true,\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "BOOLEAN") {
    componentTag = "ui:inputCheckbox";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "PHONE") {
    componentTag = "ui:inputPhone";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else if (fieldSet[0].FieldType == "ENCRYPTEDSTRING") {
    componentTag = "lightning:input";
    uiComponent.push("\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"type\": \"password\",\"label\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + ",\"value\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldValue + ",\"class\": " + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "");
} else {
    componentTag = "lightning:input";
    uiComponent.push('\"aura:id\": \"text-Value\",\"label\": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldLabel + '",\"class\": "' + fieldSet[0].FieldName + "'");
}

$A.createComponent(componentTag, {
        uiComponent
    },
    function(result, status, errorMessage) {
        bodyComponents.push(result);
        //Add the new button to the body array
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var body = component.get('v.body');
            body.push(result);
            component.set('v.body', bodyComponents);
        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            // Show offline error
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
            // Show error message
        }
    }
);
```

Here fieldSet is an array which has all the information regarding **FieldType, FieldLabel, FieldName** everything. 
But when it renders it just creates an `inputText` without any label or anything. 
I am sure I am doing wrong at assigning values at **uiComponent**. 
I tried all the possible ways taking it as a string all other ways I know.

If anyone can help me here it would be great. Let me know if anything clarification is required from my side.

PS - I have all the variable declared. if it is missing in code please assume it is there.

Edit - adding the output screen shot
[image]

Comment: I guess you iterating over a list of FieldSets?!  If so, be sure you did not hard code `[0]` but `[i]` or similar. Did you try to debug fieldSet[i]? what does it show?

Comment: for now I have only 1 value in fieldSet thats why I have hard coded it. values in FieldSet is coming correctly.

Comment: it is working when I am creating it as standard way. `$A.createComponent(
                                    "ui:inputDate", {
                                        "aura:id": "text-Value",
                                        "multiple": "true",
                                        "label": fieldSet[0].FieldLabel,
                                        "value": fieldSet[0].FieldValue,
                                        "class": fieldSet[0].FieldName
                                    }` but not if I pass it as above

Comment: oh okay. Why are you pushing a single string to your uiComponent? the format should be: `Map<String, Object>`. So it should look like this: `uiComponent = {"aura:id" : "text-Value", .... }` And than use `$A.createComponent( componentTag, uiComponent, `

Comment: Maybe you should get familiar with javascript syntax for [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: ok I let me try

Comment: @Basti I tried changing it to map as well `uiComponent = {"aura:id":"date-value", "label": fieldSet[0].FieldLabel, "value": fieldSet[0].FieldValue, "displayDatePicker": true, "class": fieldSet[0].FieldName};` but still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

As I did not find an answer from anywhere.. 
This is not possible to do it either with Map or array. Better to write the complete code.